# C# structs documentation: relation of contructor initializers to `ref` and `out` parameters

Tags: c#, struct

In C# documentation and particulary Structs I found these sentences which I can't understand:

> If the struct instance constructor doesn't specify a constructor initializer, the this variable corresponds to an out parameter of the struct type, and similar to an out parameter, this must be definitely assigned (Definite assignment) at every location where the constructor returns. If the struct instance constructor specifies a constructor initializer, the this variable corresponds to a ref parameter of the struct type, and similar to a ref parameter, this is considered definitely assigned on entry to the constructor body.

I want to know what is the relation between this keyword in constructors and, the ref and out keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not familiar with the terms used in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#constructors) this might seem a bit convoluted, but let's take it step by step.

Basic rule is: Struct constructors must ensure all fields of a struct instance has been initialized. No exceptions.

Also, relevant for the following is that a "constructor initializer" means you're chaining calls through multiple constructors:

```
public YourStruct(...) : this(...)
                       ^----+----^
                            |
                            +-- constructor initializer
```

For reference, `out` and `ref` parameters to methods:

```
public void Test(out int x) { ... }
public void Test(ref int x) { ... }
```

means that the `out int x` parameter has to be fully initialized **in** the method, and is considered unassigned at the start of the method. See the [out parameter modifier documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) for reference.

Whereas the `ref int x` parameter is considered assigned at the start of the method, and the method *can* change it but does not have to. See the [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) for more information.

So, let's take the rest of the documentation now.

If you do **not** have a constructor initializer for your constructor, then it means your constructor has to tackle the basic rule all by itself. This is what it means that it is similar to an `out` parameter for a method, your constructor has to fully initialize the struct instance before returning.

However, if you **do** have a constructor initializer, then **that** constructor *also* has to fully initialize the struct instance and so by the time *your* constructor gets to execute, the instance is *already* fully initialized. In this case, your constructor does not have to initialize all the fields any more but can selectively change only the fields it needs. This is what it means regarding the `ref` parameter.

Let me give an example:

```
public struct X
{
    public int A;
    public int B;

    public X(int a, int b)
    {
        // no constructor initializer, MUST initialize both A and B
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

However:

```
public struct X
{
    public int A;
    public int B;

    public X(int a)
        : this(a, 0)
    {
        // constructor initializer, DOES NOT have to initialize anything
        // you can, though, if you want to change B
        B++;
    }

    public X(int a, int b)
    {
        // no constructor initializer, MUST initialize both A and B
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

So basically the documentation states:

- If you DO NOT have a constructor initializer, the constructor has to fully initialize the `this` variable, *similar* to how an `out` parameter works
- If you DO have a constructor initializer, the constructor DOES NOT have to do anything, and you can consider the `this` variable similar to a `ref` parameter instead.

Comment: Very good answer, but I think it would help if you would briefly explain or link to the meaning of `ref` and `out` parameters in the beginning as well.

Comment: Wow ,thanks alot, it is a great  a great a great and helpful answer. I love it. @Lasse V.karlsen